# Creating multiple UDFs in one batch - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm asking this question for SQL Server 2008 R2

I'd like to know if there is a way to create multiple functions in a single batch statement.

I've made the following code as an example; suppose I want to take a character string and rearrange its letters in alphabetical order. So, 'Hello' would become 'eHllo'

```
CREATE FUNCTION char_split (@string varchar(max))
RETURNS @characters TABLE 
(
chars varchar(2)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @length int,
            @K      int

    SET @length = len(@string)
    SET @K = 1

    WHILE @K < @length+1
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @characters
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@string,@K,1)
            SET @K = @K+1
        END

    RETURN
END


CREATE FUNCTION rearrange (@string varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SplitData TABLE  (
    chars varchar(2)
    )

    INSERT INTO @SplitData SELECT * FROM char_split(@string)

    DECLARE @Output varchar(max)

    SELECT @Output = coalesce(@Output,' ') + cast(chars as varchar(10)) 
    from @SplitData
    order by chars asc

    RETURN @Output
END

declare @string varchar(max)
set @string = 'Hello'
select dbo.rearrange(@string)
```

When I try running this code, I get this error:

```
 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

I tried enclosing each function in a BEGIN END block, but no luck. Any advice?

Comment: Just use a GO statement between the definition of the UDFs

Comment: Hahahaha, I was actually just about to answer my own question! Yup.... using 'GO' worked like a charm. I'll leave the question up in case it's helpful for anyone else.

Comment: It would be best to actually post that as the answer and accept it, for those who come here later.

Comment: @Jonathan Ok, already did that

Answer (score 8):

Just use a `GO` statement between the definition of the UDFs

Comment: Technically that is not valid as it strips them into multiple batches - GO is a batch delimiter. And the question asks for ONE batch.

Comment: @TomTom This is correct. I think the OP needs to rephrase the question, since IMHO what he really wanted was to execute an sql script containing the definition of more than one UDFs.

Answer (score 1):

Not doable. SImple like that.

YOu can make it is one statement using a GO between them.

But as the GO is a batch delimiter.... this means you send multiple batches, which is explicitly NOT Wanted in your question.

So, no - it is not possible to do that in one batch as the error clearly indicates.